# Search Box with autocomplete jquery

Tags: php

I am trying to implement Instant Search Box with autocomplete (jQuery). 
For some reason autocomplete is not working.

### HTML

```
<input id="searchBar" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
```

### PHP - slim framework

```
$app->get('/ajaxsearchbox', function() {

    $query = $_REQUEST['query'];

    if (isset($query)) {

        $sql = DB::query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE playerName LIKE '%$query%'");

        foreach ($sql as $result[]) ;
    };
    echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
});
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#searchBar").bind("change keyup input", function () {
        /* Get input value on change */
        var term = $(this).val();

        if (term.length) {
            $.getJSON("/ajaxsearchbox", {query: term}).done(function (data) {

                $.each(data.result, function () {

                    $("#searchBar").autocomplete("<p>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>");

                });
            });
        } else {

            $("#searchBar").html("No results");
        }
    });

})
```

Comment: it just does not work. I think I did not implemented correctly this line

Comment: $("#searchBar").autocomplete("<p>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>");

Comment: bind("change keyup input") -> why input is used here ? it should not be

Comment: What says the console of the browser? Do you get a response? What does this response look like? Are there error messages in the console?

Comment: instead of autocomple use text

Comment: everything is working if I use html instead of autocomplete. But I need autosuggestion box just below the Search Box . That is the reason I am trying to implement autocomplete.

Comment: What does the console say? Is a request send? What looks the response like?

Comment: no error , nothing

Comment: I am getting data from database converting to json